# How to store secure string in Android?

Tags: android, security, passwords, keystore

Is there any understandable examples of using KeyStore in Android?

I can't really understand how do I have to protect my password/token/anything_else in Android application in ROOTED device from being used by hackers who have physical access to the device.

I understand i can generate KeyPair with some ALIAS, and use it's private key as database password for example, but I'am interested in: can any hacker read this ALIAS from my decompiled apk(because i can't obfuscate alias string) and build another app which uses same ALIAS to get privateKey from android KeyStore?

Any solutions?

Comment: for now, only solution I found is to store my data in database, encrypted by SqlCipher. 
Access with ormLite, password storing in NDK method as constant.
In my DbHelper extends OrmLiteOpenHelper I'am initializing DB with password which return method from NDK. in NDK method this is just return "secretpassword".
Bulletproof Android book says it's more difficult to get this constant from NDK, because you have to disassemble it, not just decompile like Java code.
Any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 2):

> I can't really understand how do I have to protect my password/token/anything_else in Android application in ROOTED device from being used by hackers who have physical access to the device.

You can't. [Client Authenticity is Not the Server's Problem](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem).

Let's say you store an encrypted value in your app rather than storing the value directly. Where's the key to decrypt this value? The app will necessarily need to decrypt this value. Now all a hacker needs to do is download your .apk, plug it into Lobotomy, and they will quickly figure out what's going on.

You're better off simply never placing sensitive information on the device itself, if you want to hide it from the people who run your software.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to store the key in the app?

What if at first install you ask the user to set a password, you encrypt your SQLCipher DB with that key (maybe hash it too) , then every time, when the user starts the app, you ask the password.